# Java ArrayList size with empty element []

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one ArrayList, for some reason i have to add empty string element "":

```
ArrayList<String> rList = new ArrayList<String>();
rList.add("");
```

When I read the size of the array list rList then, rList.size() == 1 and rList.isEmpty() == false.

How can I check this kind of array list? does the empty element cause the size equals 1 and not empty?

Comment: Yes, in mathematics a set which consists of only an empty set is empty. Here the collection doesn't care about the value of the string, but about its presence.

Comment: Wait, what?  The set of the empty set is nonempty in mathematics; e.g. it's 1 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers .

Comment: What do you mean `How can I check this kind of array list?`

Comment: @DrewKennedy, I mean I want to check the array list only contains "" element, if it does, I will do something.

Comment: I added an answer that pertains to that portion of your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though you're adding an empty string to your list, you're still adding *something* to the list. And, that's what counts.

The data may be empty (or even `null`, as an `ArrayList` will allow you to insert `null`), but the size will increase (and the list won't be empty).

Now, if you only want to check that there's just that *sort* of element in your list (as you state in comments), then that's possible like this:

```
if(rList.size() == 1 && "".equals(rList.get(0)) {
    // perform work
}
```

The line above will only succeed if there's just one entry in the list, and only if it's the empty string.  The reverse of the string literal and `get` is to guard against a `NullPointerException`, as that can occur if you have it flipped the other way 'round, and there's `null` in for element 0.

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a String is empty:
String x ="";
boolean isXEmpty = x.isEmpty();

Yes, the empty String instance is a valid instance as any other String. So it will count.

Comment: Thanks, I think i can follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To check empty list use this code:
Even list size 1 but its get() method return null.
so that you can ensure that actually list have no value.

```
if(someList.get(0)!=null)
```

Comment: This might still throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException though if the list contains no elements.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question `How can I check this kind of array list?`, you can check the indices to see if your ArrayList contains any particular value by iterating through it.

```
ArrayList<String> rList = new ArrayList<String>();
rList.add("");

for (String item : rList) {
    if (item.equals("")) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

If you're checking if all indices of your ArrayList are empty Strings, one way is to add a counter and compare it to the size of the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String> rList = new ArrayList<String>();
rList.add("");
rList.add("");
rList.add("");

int crossCheck = 0;

for (String item : rList) {
    if (item == null) {//equals() will throw a NPE when checking for null values
        //do something
    } else if (item.isEmpty()) {
        crossCheck++;
        //do something
    }
}
//both are 3 in this case
if (rList.size() == crossCheck) {
    //all indices are empty Strings
}
```

Makoto has an excellent answer for the rest of your question.

Comment: What happens if the list contains a `null` entry?

Comment: Nowhere is an index being null mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well no, but that's not my point.  We've established that a list can contain `null` and be non-empty; if you want to be certain that you don't get a `NullPointerException`, you have to reorder the `equals`.